# Prove by strong induction the Jacobstahl Series

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I am just beginning to learn about strong induction, I can't figure out how to complete this homework question:

Jacobstahl numbers are defined as
$$J_1 = 1$$
$$J_2 = 1$$
$$J_n = J_{n-1} + 2J_{n-2}$$

Prove:
$$J_n = 2^{n-1}-J_{n-1}$$
for n >= 2.

Here is what I have done so far:

Assume:

$$J_k = 2^{k-1} + J_{k-1}$$
then
$$J_{k+1} = 2^{k+0} - J_{k+0}$$

Then from the definition:

$$J_{k+1} = 2^{k+0} - J_{k+0} = 2^{k-1}-J_{k-1}+2(2^{k-2}-J_{k-2})$$
$$2^{k+0} - J_{k+0} = 2^{k-1}-j_{k-1}+2^1*2^{k-2} - 2^1*J_{k-2}$$
$$= 2(2^{k-1})-J_{k-1}-2J_{k-2}$$
$$= 2^{k+0} - J_{k-1}-2J_{k-2}$$

So I have gotten part of the way there, by finding the $2^{k+0}$ term, but I'm not sure what to do with the rest of it.  I think I've probably gone wrong in setting up the assumption, but I can't work out how.

Comment: Also, sorry about the formatting, I'm not sure if it is OK, this is my first post to this stack.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption for strong induction should be that $J_k=2^{k-1}-J_{k-1}$ for $k=2,\ldots,n$; from that assumption you want to prove that $J_{n+1}=2^n-J_n$. If you then attempt the usual kind of argument, your calculation of $J_{n+1}$ will start like this:

$$\begin{align*}
J_{n+1}&=J_n+2J_{n-1}\\
&=\left(2^{n-1}-J_{n-1}\right)+2J_{n-1}\\
&=2^{n-1}+J_{n-1}\\
&=2^{n-1}+2^{n-2}-J_{n-2}\,.
\end{align*}$$

It’s pretty clear that if you continue in the most straightforward fashion, replacing $J_{n-2}$ by $2^{n-3}-J_{n-3}$, you’ll still have a $J_k$ term of some kind: you’re not obviously reaching what you want.

It actually is possible to get somewhere this way, but for a simple induction proof you’re better off looking at the desired relationship in a different way. Notice that $J_k=2^{k-1}-J_{k-1}$ is equivalent to $J_k+J_{k-1}=2^{k-1}$. Thus, we could just as well assume as our induction hypothesis that $J_k+J_{k-1}=2^{k-1}$ for $k=2,\ldots,n$ and try to prove that $J_{n+1}+J_n=2^n$. Then

$$J_{n+1}+J_n=J_n+2J_{n-1}+J_n\,;$$

now just simplify that and apply the induction hypothesis. (You’ll find that you don’t actually need strong induction here: ordinary induction is enough.)

Comment: I understand why my original approach won't work.  I don't really understand what you suggest though.  I see the formula you give simplifies to $J_{n+1} = J_n + 2J_{n-1}$, which is basically the given $J_n = J_{n-1} + 2J_{n-2}$, which seems like circular reasoning to me.  I'm struggling with the basic idea of what should be accomplished.

Comment: @nexus_2006: We’re not proving that $J_{n+1}=J_n+2J_{n-1}$; that is indeed given. We’re **using** that fact to prove that **if** $J_n=2^{n-1}-J_{n-1}$, **then** $J_{n+1}=2^n-J_n$, except that we’re proving that in the equivalent form $J_{n+1}+J_n=2^n$.